# Trying to find an overpopulation dystopian anthology

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I once had this book from a library book sale, which had a collection of sci-fi short stories regarding overpopulation.  It was my first exposure to arcologies, but alas, I sold it off long ago.

Comment: Just to clarify -- was this a collection of several stories by different authors? As opposed to one author having written several short stories which were all set in the *same* imaginary future, where practically everybody lived inside one arcology or another?

Comment: Thanks it was an anthology from the 1970s, hardcover, which I got from a public library.  The authors varied and the tropes varied as well.  Once someone posted the title no room for man, I remember that phrase as the title.  Thanks for suggestions, I'll be rereading the answer and the other suggestions shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility is "[No Room for Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?301853)", an over-population themed anthology.

[image]

Contents

- Billennium • (1961) • short story by J. G. Ballard
- Total Environment • (1968) • novelette by Brian W. Aldiss
- In the Beginning • (1970) • short story by Robert Silverberg
- Feeding the Billions: World Food Problems • (1979) • essay by Joseph
  D. Olander and Martin H. Greenberg and Ralph S. Clem
- Shark Ship • (1958) • novelette by C. M. Kornbluth
- Roommates • (1971) • novelette by Harry Harrison
- Population: Impact on the Environment and Resources • (1979) • essay
  by Joseph D. Olander and Martin H. Greenberg and Ralph S. Clem
- Eco-Catastrophe! • (1969) • short story by Paul R. Ehrlich
- "East Wind, West Wind" • (1972) • novelette by Frank M. Robinson
- Solutions? • (1979) • essay by Joseph D. Olander and Martin H.
  Greenberg and Ralph S. Clem
- The Secret • (1971) • short story by Maggie Nadler
- The Census Takers • (1956) • short story by Frederik Pohl
- Statistician's Day • (1970) • short story by James Blish
- Triage • (1976) • short story by William Walling
- Afterword (No Room for Man) • (1979) • essay by Joseph D. Olander and
  Martin H. Greenberg and Ralph S. Clem
- Probability Zero! The Population Implosion • (1973) • short story by
  Theodore R. Cogswell
- Dolls' Demise • (1976) • short story by George Guthridge

Comment: This was the anthology I was thinking of!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Perhaps the 1971 paperback anthology [*Voyages: Scenarios for a Ship Called Earth*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?53587) (Rob Sauer, ed.), "A [Zero Population Growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_Connection)/Ballantine Book" with a foreword by [Dr. Paul R. Ehrlich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_R._Ehrlich) and Anne H. Ehrlich? Some of the individual stories are available online:

[*Nigger of the Narcissus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nigger_of_the_%27Narcissus%27) (Excerpt) by Joseph Conrad, at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/17731).

"Billennium" by J. G. Ballard, at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/New_Worlds_112v38_1961-11#page/n43/mode/2up).

"All Summer in a Day" by Ray Bradbury, at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v006n03_1954-03/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v006n03_1954-03#page/n123/mode/2up).

"The Heat Death of the Universe" by Pamela Zoline, at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/New_Worlds_173v51_1967-07#page/n33/mode/2up).

"Student Body" by Floyd L. Wallace, at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v05n06_1953-03.Galaxy/Galaxy%20v05n06%20%281953-03.Galaxy%29#page/n79/mode/2up).

"The Choice" by Wayland Hilton-Young, at [www.101bananas.com](http://www.101bananas.com/library2/thechoice.html).

"The Tunnel Ahead" by Alice Glaser, at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v021n05_1961-11_PDF/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v021n05_1961-11_PDF#page/n51/mode/2up).

"Consumer's Report" by Theodore R. Cogswell, aka "No Gun to the Victor", at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Imagination_v06n08_1955-10_LennyS-cape1736#page/n103/mode/2up).

"Shark Ship" by C. M. Kornbluth, aka "Reap the Dark Tide", at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Vanguard_v01n01_1958-06_Gorgon776#page/n99/mode/2up).

Comment: thanks for the idea, I will have to check out this book even though it wasn't the one I was thinking of.